# How to use custom embeddings with keras LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to use pre-trained word embeddings with an LSTM.

That is I already have a model of form:

```
embedding_for_word = model[word]
```

I have data of the following form:

```
1. "word1 word2 word3" label 0
2. "word4 word5 word6 word7" label 1
3. "word8 word9" label 1
...
..
.
```

I know that for a standard LSTM (if timesteps are fixed) we can have:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(N, input_shape=(n_timesteps, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

How do I give sequential input of the form:

```
batch_1[embedding_word1,
embedding_word2,embedding_word3 .. some_end_of_sequence_character] --> label 0
batch_2[embedding_word4,
embedding_word5,embedding_word,embedding_word7,some_end_of_sequence_character] --> label 1
...
..
.
```

How do I engineer the data and create the model (For the model, I'm only asking what the input layer would look like) for the example above?

Assume:

size_of_embeddings = K
batch_size = B

Answer (score 1):

You should have something to pad the missing words up to the length of the sequence. 
Probably a "sentence end" embedding would be interesting.

So, you will need:

- one array with shape: `(total_sentences, words, embedding_size)` - This is `X`, inputs
- one array with shape: `(total_sentences, total_labels)` - This is `Y`, outputs

You can then use `fit(X, Y)`, maybe with a train test split.

The first layer of the model can be the `LSTM(input_shape=(words, embedding_size), ...)`.

Comment: Are embeddings learned by keras `static` or `dynamic` (or contextualized)?

Comment: @A.B, I don't understand your questios. Embeddings are trainable weights. You choose whether you train them or not. Context doesn't have anything to do with the frameworks, but with the data and how you train your models.

Comment: Thanyou for reply. I was confused about "static" vs "dynamic" embedding approach. For instance, having embedding layer followed by lstm for next word prediction,  will it be called dynamic embedding approach as lstm does force these "trainable weights" to have context, right?